# Using rbind correctly

Tags: r, rbind

For reasons not relevant, let's assume I want to use rbind like so:

`df.new = rbind(df.old, c(1, 2, 1, 1)`

BUT, the issue is that `df.new` has 5 columns, not 4. I want to leave the last field blank by design. Is this possible using `rbind`?

Comment: `rbindlist` from `data.table` package has an arg `fill` for such cases - would automatically fill out `NA`s for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NA` as a placeholder in the columns you want to leave blank:

```
df.new = rbind(df.old, c(1, 2, 1, 1, NA))
```